# Morse code symbols represented by sequences of seven or fewer dots and dashes

Tags: combinatorics

In Morse code, symbols are represented by variable length sequences of dots and dashes. (For example, A = · −, 1 = · − − − −, and ? = · · − − · ·.) How many different symbols can be represented by sequences of seven or fewer dots and dashes?

I don't have a answer for this question but my solution is:
$2^1$ + $2^2$ + $2^3$ + $2^4$ + $2^5$ + $2^6$ +$ 2^7$ $= 254$. Is that correct?

Comment: If $254$ is not (a suggestion of) an "answer", what do you mean by "answer"?

Comment: By the way, yes there are $254$ possible codes, if you do not consider gaps in-between.

Comment: This is a verbatim homework problem from the textbook Discrete Mathematics with Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
There are $2^n$ Morse strings of length exactly $n$, and the number of non-empty strings of length at most seven is obtained by summing over strings of length $1$, ..., $7$.